# Drawing discs with circular holes with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the TikZ package to show a set of complex numbers where those I want are in the outer part of a circle with a radius 2, and where the circle with radius 1 is not in the set:
[image]

I want to let the inner circle be white, with the axes showing completely, but I am not able to find out how. I am using two circles with semi-transparent fillings. Is there any way to make only the outer part filled? Relevant code below.

(This is where I got most of the code: [Drawing a circle in the complex plane.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18260/drawing-a-circle-in-the-complex-plane))

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[thick,font=\scriptsize][set layers]
    \draw [->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node [above left]  {$\Re\{z\}$};
    \draw [->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node [below right] {$\Im\{z\}$};
    \iffalse% Single
    \draw (1,-3pt) -- (1,3pt)   node [above] {$1$};
    \draw (-1,-3pt) -- (-1,3pt) node [above] {$-1$};
    \draw (-3pt,1) -- (3pt,1)   node [right] {$i$};
    \draw (-3pt,-1) -- (3pt,-1) node [right] {$-i$};
    \else% Multiple
    \foreach \n in {-3,...,-1,1,2,...,3}{%
        \draw (\n,-3pt) -- (\n,3pt)   node [above] {$\n$};
        \draw (-3pt,\n) -- (3pt,\n)   node [right] {$\n i$};
    }
    \fi
    \end{scope}
    \draw[solid] (0,-1) circle (1);
    \draw[solid] (0,-1) circle (2);
    \path [draw=none,fill=gray, fill opacity = 0.1] (0,-1) circle (2);
    \path [draw=none,fill=white, fill opacity = 0.7] (0,-1) circle (1);
    \node [below right,black] at (1.2,1.2) {$A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:1\leq|z-(-i)|\leq2\}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use a different fill rule which is called `even odd rule` that fills every even numbered closed region.

So if you use the following line instead of two distinct circles you get a donut fill;

```
\path [draw=none,fill=gray, fill opacity = 0.1,even odd rule] (0,-1) circle (2) (0,-1) circle (1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

In this particular case, you can simply change the drawing order i.e., draw the circles first:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \path [draw=none,fill=gray, fill opacity = 0.1] (0,-1) circle (2);
    \path [draw=none,fill=white] (0,-1) circle (1);
    \begin{scope}[thick,font=\scriptsize][set layers]
    \draw [->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node [above left]  {$\Re\{z\}$};
    \draw [->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node [below right] {$\Im\{z\}$};
    \iffalse% Single
    \draw (1,-3pt) -- (1,3pt)   node [above] {$1$};
    \draw (-1,-3pt) -- (-1,3pt) node [above] {$-1$};
    \draw (-3pt,1) -- (3pt,1)   node [right] {$i$};
    \draw (-3pt,-1) -- (3pt,-1) node [right] {$-i$};
    \else% Multiple
    \foreach \n in {-3,...,-1,1,2,...,3}{%
        \draw (\n,-3pt) -- (\n,3pt)   node [above] {$\n$};
        \draw (-3pt,\n) -- (3pt,\n)   node [right] {$\n i$};
    }
    \fi
    \end{scope}
    \draw[solid] (0,-1) circle (1);
    \draw[solid] (0,-1) circle (2);
%    \path [draw=none,fill=gray, fill opacity = 0.1] (0,-1) circle (2);
%    \path [draw=none,fill=white, fill opacity = 0.7] (0,-1) circle (1);
    \node [below right,black] at (1.2,1.2) {$A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:1\leq|z-(-i)|\leq2\}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Use the 'even odd rule':

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[thick,font=\scriptsize][set layers]
    \draw [->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node [above left]  {$\Re\{z\}$};
    \draw [->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node [below right] {$\Im\{z\}$};
    \iffalse% Single
    \draw (1,-3pt) -- (1,3pt)   node [above] {$1$};
    \draw (-1,-3pt) -- (-1,3pt) node [above] {$-1$};
    \draw (-3pt,1) -- (3pt,1)   node [right] {$i$};
    \draw (-3pt,-1) -- (3pt,-1) node [right] {$-i$};
    \else% Multiple
    \foreach \n in {-3,...,-1,1,2,...,3}{%
        \draw (\n,-3pt) -- (\n,3pt)   node [above] {$\n$};
        \draw (-3pt,\n) -- (3pt,\n)   node [right] {$\n i$};
    }
    \fi
    \end{scope}
    \draw[solid] (0,-1) circle (1);
    \draw[solid] (0,-1) circle (2);
    \path [draw=none, fill=gray, even odd rule, fill opacity = 0.1] (0,-1) circle (2) (0,-1) circle (1);
    \node [below right,black] at (1.2,1.2) {$A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:1\leq|z-(-i)|\leq2\}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: even odd filling]

## EDIT

Since percusse was faster with the even-odd rule solution (but did not, I note, provide a complete MWE), here's a solution you can use if you want the inner circle filled but you still want the axes on top. This solution uses the `backgrounds` library to fill the inner circle *behind* the rest of the picture, so that the axes remain on top.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[thick,font=\scriptsize][set layers]
      \draw [->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node [above left]  {$\Re\{z\}$};
      \draw [->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node [below right] {$\Im\{z\}$};
      \iffalse % Single
      \draw (1,-3pt) -- (1,3pt)   node [above] {$1$};
      \draw (-1,-3pt) -- (-1,3pt) node [above] {$-1$};
      \draw (-3pt,1) -- (3pt,1)   node [right] {$i$};
      \draw (-3pt,-1) -- (3pt,-1) node [right] {$-i$};
      \else% Multiple
      \foreach \n in {-3,...,-1,1,2,...,3}{%
        \draw (\n,-3pt) -- (\n,3pt)   node [above] {$\n$};
        \draw (-3pt,\n) -- (3pt,\n)   node [right] {$\n i$};
      }
      \fi
    \end{scope}
    \draw[solid] (0,-1) circle (1);
    \draw[solid] (0,-1) circle (2);
    \path [fill=gray, fill opacity = 0.1] (0,-1) circle (2);
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \path [fill=white, fill opacity=.7] (0,-1) circle (1);
    \end{scope}
    \node [below right,black] at (1.2,1.2) {$A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:1\leq|z-(-i)|\leq2\}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: answer a different question using backgrounds library]

Answer (score 5):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\set}{\lbrace}{\rbrace}

\newcommand*\mathsetfont{\mathbb}
\newcommand*\DeclareMathSet[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname set#1\endcsname{\mathsetfont{#1}}
}
\DeclareMathSet{C}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.9,-3.9)(6.5,4.55)
  \psaxes[
    xlabelPos = t,
    ylabelPos = r,
    ylabelFactor = {i}
  ]{->}(0,0)(-3.9,-3.9)(4,4)[$\Re\{z\}$,0][$\Im\{z\}$,90]
  \psRing*[
    opacity = 0.3
  ](0,-1){1}{2}
  \rput(4,2){$A = \set*{z \in \setC : 1 \leq \abs*{z - (-i)} \leq 2}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that it may be rather cumbersome to write the set of complex numbers as I've done but with this approach you get a clear code syntax and it's both easy to change and add new sets.

P.S. With the option `ylabelPos = r`, you get an

> overfull `\hbox`

warning but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 4):

Done with MetaPost (via LuaLaTeX), for whom it may interest.

With the help of the Metafun format for the transparent filling:

```
fill ring withcolor transparent(1, 0.1, \mpcolor{gray});
```

The ring itself is created by appending one of the circles to the reversed other circle:

```
ring = circle1 -- reverse circle2 -- cycle;
```

(Of course a simpler and quicker method would have been to fill the biggest circle and unfill the smallest one, but I found it interesting to create this ring path and directly fill it.)

The full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb, xcolor}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
u = 1.5cm; xmax = 3.9 = ymax = -ymin = -xmin; len = 6bp;
path circle[], ring;
circle1 = fullcircle scaled 2u shifted (0, -u);
circle2 = fullcircle scaled 4u shifted (0, -u);
ring = circle1 -- reverse circle2 -- cycle;
labeloffset := 6bp;
beginfig(1);
    for i = ceiling(xmin) upto floor(xmax):
        draw (i*u, -0.5len) -- (i*u, 0.5len); 
        if i <> 0: label.top("$" & decimal i & "$", (i*u, 0)); fi
    endfor
    for j = ceiling(ymin) upto floor(ymax):
        draw (-0.5len, j*u) -- (0.5len, j*u); 
        if j <> 0: label.rt("$" & decimal j & "i$", (0, j*u)); fi
    endfor
    drawarrow (xmin*u, 0) -- (xmax*u, 0); label.top("$\Re\{ z \}$", (xmax*u, 0));
    drawarrow (0, ymin*u) -- (0, ymax*u); label.rt("$\Im\{ z \}$", (0, ymax*u));
    fill ring withcolor transparent(1, 0.1, \mpcolor{gray});
    for i = 1,2: draw circle[i]; endfor
    label.urt("$A = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: 1 \leqslant |z-(-i)| \leqslant2 \}$", 
        point 1.5 of circle2);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `even odd rule` works to not fill inside the smaller circle as shown in the answer of @percusse.

But if you want to decorate your path with arrows, it could be useful to revers the orientation of the circle. This can be done with the following style :

```
\tikzset{
  reversed with radius/.style={
    x radius=#1,
    y radius=-#1,
 }
}
```

You can use it like this

```
\draw[preaction={fill,opacity=.1}, with arrows]
  circle[reversed with radius=1cm]
  circle[radius=2cm];
```

to obtain something like this :

[image]

where the style `with arrows` is defined as

```
\tikzset{
  with arrows/.style={
    decoration={ markings,
      mark=between positions #1 and .999 step #1 with {\arrow{stealth}}
    }, postaction={decorate}
  }, with arrows/.default=25mm,
}
```