# tikz fit with rounded corners: color crosses corners

Tags: tikz-pgf

mwe:
https://www.latex4technics.com?note=zzvqsa

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{fit} 

\begin{tikzpicture}


\node[fill=green,inner sep=0pt] (content) {
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \cellcolor{blue!25} & \cellcolor{red!25} 
    \end{tabular}
}; % node
\node[draw,inner sep=0pt,rounded corners,fit=(content)](a){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Problem: colored sharp corners not cropped by rounded corners
Question: how to?

Comment: You are adding the rounded corner node *after* drawing the tabular with square corners... so that's expected. One possible solution is coloring the node afterward using `on background layer`, and installing a clip. Not easy...

Comment: but its not actually the node that is colored but the table cell

Comment: Yes --- that is the problem. Once is drawn, you can't clip it.

Comment: one workaround could be to overlay another node that is the difference of (a) and (a) with sharp corners - but I would not know how to create that

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `path picture`. The `multifill` style defined here takes a color list and fills the node background with these colors. It splits the fills equally but one can generalize this to allow for arbitrary fractions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[multifill/.style={path picture={
  \edef\icnt{0}%
  \edef\ppbb{path picture bounding box}%
  \tikzset{step/.list={#1}}%
  \foreach\mycolor [count=\istep]in {#1}
  {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxfl}{(\istep-1)/\icnt} 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myxfr}{\istep/\icnt} 
  \fill[\mycolor,rounded corners=false] 
    ($(\ppbb.south west)!\myxfl!(\ppbb.south east)$)
    rectangle ($(\ppbb.north west)!\myxfr!(\ppbb.north east)$);}
    }},step/.code={\edef\icnt{\the\numexpr\icnt+1}}]
 \path node[draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,
    rounded corners,multifill={blue!20,red!20}] {}
    (4,0) node[draw,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=1cm,
    rounded corners,multifill={blue!20,red!20,orange!20}]   {};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `rectangle split` from `shapes.multipart` library?

[image: rectangle split]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rounded corners,rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts=2,rectangle split part fill={blue!25,red!25}] (A) {};
        \node[rounded corners,fit=(A),draw,inner sep=0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I took the following mwe from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527525/238944 ; for more complicated shapes another problem would occur: example:  https://latex4technics.com?note=zzvqsb ; see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591383/split-rectangle-with-rounded-corners-only-specific-corners

Comment: I edited my answer to be able to draw only the outer line.

Answer (score 1):

You can "white out" the corners if you use a `\draw` instead of an additional node.

Using the `even odd rule` of filling, if you draw a rectangle and then another one, only the internal "border" will be filled. See also [Drawing discs with circular holes with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202607/drawing-discs-with-circular-holes-with-tikz)

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[fill=green,inner sep=0pt, ] (content) {
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \cellcolor{blue!25} & \cellcolor{red!25}
    \end{tabular}
}; % node
\path [fill=white, rounded corners, even odd rule]
    (content.north west) rectangle (content.south east)
    ([xshift=-3pt, yshift=3pt]content.north west) rectangle
    ([xshift=3pt, yshift=-3pt]content.south east)
    ;
\draw [rounded corners]
    (content.north west) rectangle (content.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]