# Plot of rectangle in the complex plane using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

How do I achieve following graphic using tikz?

[image]

My attempt until now is

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,-3)--(0,3);
        \draw (4,-3)--(4,3);
        \draw (-.5,0)--(4.5,0);
        \draw [pattern = north east lines, pattern color = black] (0,-2) rectangle (4,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

How do I increase the spacing between the diagonal lines filling the rectangle?

Comment: Related: [Drawing a circle in the complex plane](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18260/), may just need to replace the `circle` in either answer with an appropriately-sized `rectangle`.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at it but I think it is not exactly what I want. I added my progress to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TikZ defines `north east lines` using

```
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{north east lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{4pt}{4pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.1pt}{3.1pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
```

where it seems like it defines a rectangle from the first point to the second point and repeats starting at the third point.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{my lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{10pt}{10pt}}{\pgfqpoint{9pt}{9pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{9.1pt}{9.1pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,-3)--(0,3);
        \draw (4,-3)--(4,3);
        \draw (-.5,0)--(4.5,0);
        \draw [pattern = my lines, pattern color = black] (0,-2) rectangle (4,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]